# How to clear up space on 16GB iPad for iOS upgrade?

Tags: ipad, ios, software-update

I have an iPad mini 16GB and like to upgrade to iOS 7.0.3. this upgrade wants 1.2GB of free storage. However I only have 0.5 GB at the moment.

The largest amount of data are my photostreams. They are about 3 GB can I trim them down (without losing any pictures permanently)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an iCloud account, you can enable Photo stream and sync it to your Mac or PC, then delete them on iPad, and you can upgrade.

BTW iOS 7.0.2 to 7.0.3 OTA only takes less than 1GB of space, so you can just delete some music or apps you don't want.

Comment: Indeed I could simply disable the shared photostreams, which deletes the local copies of the pictures. The main photostream is a different setting, so you can keep on syncing new photos made with the iPad.

Answer (score -3):

back up photos, songs and video to your computer, and then delete some of them.

also you can delete some unused apps on your ipad.

Comment: This is not related to Photostream as asked.

Comment: The question is "how to clear up space", the Photostream bit is the OP supplying a query on 1 potential method. This answer is perfectly valid and is trying to answer the question in ways other than expanding on the presumed answer.